# Get horizontal wise max value

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

i have a table in MySQL like below i want name and maximum horizontal value with respective name

```
Name     m1    m2     m3     m4
M1      200    300    100    275
M2      1200   300    100    275
M3      200    1300   100    275
M4      1200   300    100    1275
```

now i want result like below table the i want name and maximum horizontal value with respective name. If i want the horizontal  sum then we try `Select Name, (m1+m2+m3+m4) as total from t1;` we get horizontal sum same i want max horizontal value in each row

```
Name Max_value
M1    300
M2    1200
M3    1300
M4    1275
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)**

```
SELECT Name, GREATEST(m1, m2, m3, m4) AS Max_value
FROM yourTable
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b215e/1)**

Comment: Because its not my job to teach other people how to become better architects and build better structures :) That won't remain StackOverflow then :) They asked for it.